# Node.js cache request data from method inside class object

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, methods, constructor

I am trying to cache the data I am receiving from a get request inside a class in Node.js by invoking a method when the class is instantiated. I want to run it only one time when I create a new instance of the class.

```
class GetSomeData {

    constructor() {
        this.storedData = '';
        this.getData();
    }

    getData = async () => {
        const allData = await axios.get(`URL`, config)
        this.storedData = allData
    }
}

let newInstance = new GetSomeData();
```

when I log newInstance.storedData I get ''.
I am receiving the data back from the get request but I am not able to store it in  this.storedData.

For some reason this works:

```
class GetSomeData {

    constructor() {
        this.storedData = this.getData();
    }

    getData = async () => {
        const allData = await axios.get(`URL`, config)
        return allData 
    }
}

let newInstance = new GetSomeData();
```

when I log newInstance.storedData I get the actual data.

The second way should run the getData method every time I access newInstance.storedData but it actually runs it only one time when the new instance is being created.
I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where/when you call `console.log`.

Remember that JavaScript code execution never stops and that it remains single threaded and synchronous. Asynchronous behavior is achieved by queuing and handling tasks while interacting with external I/O interfaces (generally from the underlying OS).

Also remember that `async` functions always and implicitly return a promise once the first `await` statement is reached. Then code execution continues outside of the `async` function until the awaited promise is fulfilled.

In your first case, you are initializing your `storedData` property with an empty string, and that is what you get when you try to log it before the async request ends.

In your second case, you are actually logging a promise that will then be resolved with the fetched data and that is why you see the data.

```js
const get = async () => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('DATA');
    }, 3000);
  });
};

class GetSomeData {
    constructor() {
        this.storedDataA = '';
        this.storedDataB = this.getData();
    }

    getData = async () => {
        this.storedDataA = await get();
        return this.storedDataA;
    }
}

const instance = new GetSomeData();

console.log(instance.storedDataA);
console.log(instance.storedDataB);

instance.storedDataB.then((storedDataB) => {
  console.log(instance.storedDataA);
  console.log(storedDataB);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first attempt, the constructor kicks off an async task and returns immediately; the code creating the instance runs right away, too early to see the result.  In the second attempt, the constructor calls a method that returns after the async operation is complete.

Neither one is well-advised. Instead, don't anything async (or async and blocking) in the constructor, and place the async work in an instance method.

You can still have caching...

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
  }

  async getData() {
    if (!this.storedData) {
      this.storedData = await get('url', config)
    }
    return this.storedData
  }
}
```

The caller looks like this...

```
const myInstance = new MyClass()
const data = await myInstance.getData();
const dataButQuicker = await myInstance.getData();  // this will get cached data
```

Comment: "the constructor calls a method that returns after the async operation is complete", actually the async function returns before the async operation is complete, if not, code execution could not continue and async behavior would not be achieved. A promise is returned immediately after the first await statement is reached. Finally, that promise gets resolved to the value effectively returned by the function.